# How do I see what Reference properties and Value properties I can address in GetComponent in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties, reference

Newbie question but couldn't find an answer.

I'm making a script that generates a gradient texture procedurally to apply to a panoramic Skybox, so I can change the colors of the sky later.

I followed this tutorial for the texture script: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise/

My Main Camera has a script called 'TextureCreator' and a 'Skybox' component. The 'Skybox' component has a property called 'Custom Skybox' in the Inspector which references the 'Skybox Material' currently. I want to do the following:

```
GetComponent<Skybox>().CustomSkybox.Spherical(HDR) = myTexture;
```

But 'CustomSkybox' isn't a property with a definition!

My question: How do I see what property I need to reference in C# to reference, for instance, CustomSkybox, and later reference the Skybox material's texture so I can change it?

Comment: SkyBox does not have CustomSkybox property as far as I'm aware. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Skybox.html

Comment: Re-reading your question, I think I now understand it. Can you show a screenshot of the inspector of your Skybox?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/33a86434a8fce1da8cb69f879197a8a5.png

I believe you indirectly answered my question. 'CustomSkybox' should be the 'material' property as per the Unity manual to access the 'Skybox Material' and because the 'Skybox Material' is a material, 'mainTexture' must be set to 'myTexture'. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html

Comment: Right, but when no material is assigned you must either create a material in code first or assign a material that you will modify at runtime.